# Inverse marginal property of a collection of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics

In my paper "On the inverse best approximation property of systems of subspaces of a Hilbert space"
I introduced the Inverse marginal property (IMP) for a collection of $\sigma$-algebras.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a probability space and 
$\mathcal{F}_1,...,\mathcal{F}_n$ be sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$.
We will say that the collection $\mathcal{F}_1,...,\mathcal{F}_n$ possesses
the inverse marginal property (IMP) if for arbitrary random variables
$\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ such that

(1) $\xi_k$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable, $k=1,2,...,n$;

(2) $E|\xi_k|^2<\infty$, $k=1,2,...,n$;

(3) $E\xi_1=E\xi_2=...=E\xi_n$,

there exists a random variable $\xi$ such that $E|\xi|^2<\infty$ and 
$E(\xi|\mathcal{F}_k)=\xi_k$ for all $k=1,2,...,n$.

The simplest example of a collection of sub-$\sigma$-algebras which possesses the IMP 
is a system of pairwise independent sub-$\sigma$-algebras.
In this case a needed random variable $\xi$ 
can be defined by $\xi:=\xi_1+...+\xi_n-(n-1)a$, where
$a:=E\xi_1=E\xi_2=...=E\xi_n$.

**Question**: is the IMP a new notion or it is well-known?
Have you seen this property or something similar in the literature?

I will be very grateful for any comments on the IMP.

Comment: If one restrict to $\xi$ such that $\mathbb{E}(\xi)=0$. Is your IMP equivalent to $$ L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_1,\mu)\oplus L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_2,\mu)\oplus\cdots \oplus L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_n,\mu)$$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand your question. Please specify the question.

Comment: Just that the vector space generated by the variable $\mathcal{F}_i$ measurable are in direct sum : $\forall \xi_1,\cdots,\xi_n\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F_1},\mu)\times...\times L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F_n},\mu)$. $\xi_1+\cdots +\xi_n=0\Rightarrow \xi_1=0,\cdots,\xi_n=0$.

Comment: No, IMP **is not** equivalent to the linear independence of the marginal subspaces $L^2_0(\mathcal{F}_1),...,L^2_0(\mathcal{F}_n)$. One can show that a collection of $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}_1,...,\mathcal{F}_n$ possesses the IMP if and only if the marginal subspaces $L^2_0(\mathcal{F}_1),...,L^2_0(\mathcal{F}_n)$ are linearly independent and their sum is closed in $L^2(\mathcal{F})$. For details see my paper "On the inverse best approximation property of systems of subspaces of a Hilbert space" (available on ArXiv).

Comment: Please choose between "article" and "paper" once and for all, and stop making these needless changes.

Comment: I think this condition implies that for $i<j$ one has  $\mathcal F_i\cap \mathcal F_j$ only consists of sets of measure either $0$ or $1$ (because if $A\in \mathcal F_i\cap \mathcal F_j $  one can consider $\xi_i:=\chi_A-\mathbb P(A)$  and $\xi_k=0$ for all $k\ne i$, and deduce $0=\mathbb E \xi_i^2=\mathbb P(A)(1-\mathbb P(A)) $. From this one gets $$\oplus_kL^2(\mathcal F_k)=L^2(\sigma(\cup_k \mathcal F_k)).  $$

Comment: So  if this property has been used somewhere, I think the definition is more likely to be given in the geometric form, that does not require introducing new terms.

Answer (score -1):

I've never heard the term 'inverse marginal property', but the notion is somewhat familiar. Take any square integrable martingale $\xi_i$, $i=1,2,...$, and let $\{\mathcal{F}_n \}$ be it's natural filtration. Then I suspect for any $N < \infty$, the initial sequence $\{ \mathcal{F}_n, n \leq N \}$ has this property.

The difference is that $\xi_n$ are not *arbitrary* $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable random variables -  they're rather special. I expect that given our filtration, it is easy to construct a sequence $\{ \zeta_n \}$ adapted to $\mathcal{F}_n$ that break your IMP.

In fact, modifying your example slightly, $\xi_{k} = a + \sum_{i\leq k}(\xi_i - a)$, $k = 1, \cdots, n$ is a martingale w.r.t $\{ \mathcal{F_k} \}$. It is not an arbitrary sequence.

Could you construct a sequence of $\sigma$-algebras that satisfy IMP for *any* adapted sequence of random variables?

Comment: In the definition of the IMP the needed $\xi$ must exist for **arbitrary** random variables $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ that satisfy (1), (2), (3) in the Question.

Comment: If $\mathcal{F_1}\subset\mathcal{F}_2\subset...\subset\mathcal{F}_n$, then the collection $\mathcal{F}_1,...,\mathcal{F}_n$ **does not possess** the IMP (if the probability space is not trivial). In fact, if $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ are random variables that satisfy conditions (1),(2),(3) in the Question, then the needed $\xi$ exists if and only if $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ is a martingale with respect to $\{\mathcal{F}_1,...,\mathcal{F}_n\}$. If this is the case, then one can take $\xi=\xi_n$.

Comment: For examples of collections of $\sigma$-algebras that possess the IMP see Section 5 of my paper "On the inverse best approximation property of systems of subspaces of a Hilbert space" (it is available on ArXiv).

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}_1\subset...\subset\mathcal{F}_n$, then the collection $\mathcal{F}_1,...,\mathcal{F}_n$ does not possess the IMP (if the $\sigma$-algebras are not trivial).